# oauth2 - grant a service to make authorized http request to another server

Tags: http, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, microservices

I have a remote function (aws lambda) which is designed to make an http request to my RESTful server protected by oauth2. HTTP API needs to be authorized for this reason I would ask you: **how can I retrieve a valid access token for use in my lambda?**

My actual solution is to share the JWT Secret to let lambda function to generate a valid access token.
I'm not pretty sure about the elegance of this solution, for this reason I would ask if this solution is nice or if there are better ways. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: if the lambda is your auth service then it requires to have the secret, of course. You could protect it with AWS key management (KMS) service for another layer of protection, but ultimately the lambda will need access. Unless you perform the actual auth work on a separate server/service.

Comment: Hello @OswinNoetzelmann thanks for your answer. In my context the RESTful server is the auth service which offers API to perform login and manipulating data; lambda function is designed to perform a request to RESTful server but to do this it needs an access token. So what I'm asking is a way to authorize the Lambda function.

Comment: An access token is generated on login, which should typically be provided by an endpoint that does not require a valid token to begin with. The token should only be required on protected endpoints for services only available to users logged in. And the client will have to keep and provide the token that was originally created at login for those.